# jquery animations queued and slow on iOS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a small website that is already working on desktop browsers. But as I tested this site on my iPhone, I noticed that the animation is queued and kind of slow. I don´t get it working flawlessly. Can someone get me a hint why this is so slow on iOS browsers?! Or is the graphics engine on the iPhone not that powerful to handle this?

[link to the website](https://www.tissi-solutions.de/caches/matrix/matrix2_4.html)

Here is the code that causes me some headache:

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('#switch0').on('change', function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
            {
                $('table,#middletable').css({'border-color':'#00ff00' , 'color': '#00ff00' });
                $('.rot,.blau').fadeTo(0,0);
                $('.gruen').fadeTo(0,100);
                $("#switch1, #switch2").prop("checked", false); 
                $("td.not_neo").addClass('center_1');
                $("td.center_1").removeClass('not_neo');
                document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();   
            }
                else 
            {   
                $('table,#middletable').css({'border-color':'#009df7' , 'color': '#009df7'});
                $('.gruen').fadeTo(0,0);
                $('.blau').fadeTo(0,100);
                $("#switch1").prop("checked", true);
                $("td.center_1").addClass('not_neo');
                $("td.center_1").removeClass('center_1');
                document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

            }
            }); 
        });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Tables can be surprisingly slow, starting from 20+ rows above. It makes sense, considering number of cells, linking on both directions, the need to keep compatibility for obsolete properties. Besides, the times when browsers were optimized for tables are long gone, as tables are no longer used for layout. I had to work with tabular data lately and was surprised how slow they were. Depending on case, you might want to look at solutions such as Swimlane's [data-table](http://swimlane.github.io/angular-data-table/). It only renders the visible cells. Try the 100k rows example on iPhone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you think that using divs instead is a better way to do it? As all rows or „data“ should be visible I don‘t think that your suggested solution is the right one for me at the moment. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, I looked at it and that's not your issue. One thing I noticed is that your animations are quite slow on desktop too. I've seen slow animations due to number of items and this is not it. What you're showing here is irrelevant. How would we know what's inside the functions you call and what adding/removing classes means? When you're debugging performance changing one property instead of another makes a world of difference.

Comment: I don't want to sink your ships, but in current form your q is off-topic here. It's way too vast and we have nothing to work with so far. Come with some tests, ask a technical question. Ask why a method is better than another even though at first one might think otherwise. *"My website is slow, please help!"*, is not really a question. It's a gig. It's a job. Nobody comes here to work. We're here to show tricks, to point you gotchas, to tell what we've learned. But don't expect us to work. We're sick of work. Ask something we want to answer :)

Comment: To answer the question in prev comment, IMHO, replacing tables with divs might see drastic improvements. Multiple CSS changes in table properties require a lot of repainting and it's quite possible it creates jumps in smooth scrolling. On the other hand it might be a mix of problems, one on top of another. It's really hard to tell. Last but not least, your question will become irrelevant when you find a fix and apply it to your website, because it doesn't have a [mcve] in the question itself where the initial issue can be inspected and compared with the solution.

Comment: Dear Andrei, to be honest, I looked at your answers and just think: what do you want me to do? As you can see I am a novice and this is my first post in this forum and also the last one. Do you just want to bash me? There is a link to my website, and you can use a developer tool to inspect the whole code. I also gave a code example that in my opinion is responsible for slowing down the animations. I don´t want somebody to work for me, I just ask for your knowledge and experience as I do NOT have it. This question is not off-topic for me because it exactly tells what I have experienced.

Comment: I apologize. I don't want to bash you and I should've emphasized the  *"I don't want to sink your ships"* part more. In short, it's my way of saying: what you're asking for is quite vast. So vast it's the daily job for a large number of people. And web performance tuning is becoming more popular each day. It's my way of saying: you have a marathon ahead. Don't try to sprint it or you'll get tired fast. Your question, in current form, is so vast it can't be answered on SO. I'm genuinely trying to be nice, helpful and supportive. I wish I knew how to do it better. Good luck and enjoy your code!

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your spent time on my problem! As I am at the  boundaries of my capabilities, there was a small chance that somebody just say:"Yes, this is because of this and change this into that." I´ll give it a try by first changing all tables into divs and then working with css transitions. Maybe this will accelerate the site a little bit. I really did not know that tables are handled slower that divs. I also did not know that css is faster than jquery in some cases.

Comment: I'm 42 and enjoy learning. I do it every day and plan on doing it until I'll need to leave. Welcome on [so], @Tissi.

Comment: I changed all tables into divs - no speed improvement so far.

Comment: To do this properly, you'd need to start debugging your function. Name your function and modify it so it only does 1 of the things at once. And run it 100k times and see how much it takes. Than uncomment another line and run it alone, until you figure out what's stalling your function. You can then go deeper into what that line does, all the way till the changes operated in DOM. You'll soon find out why it's slow and maybe think of alternatives. Most probably, that would give you material for a good SO question.

Answer (score 2):

I checked it out on my iPhone X and it seems to be functioning properly without any lagging.

I think the reason this is slow on your iPhone is because the smoothness of an animation not only depends on the quality of the code but also the performance capabilities of the user's device. Outdated browsers and slow devices might be two reasons why the animations are slow on your iPhone.

Though there are ways you can enhance the performance of an animation.

- You can improve the performance of an animation by optimizing the code. You can do this by limiting DOM manipulation, keeping a close eye on the animation queue, making sure the queue doesn't get jammed, minifying the code, keeping the animations short and chaining consecutive animations accurately.
- Use CSS animations instead of jQuery animations when possible. JavaScript animations are fast but jQuery slows it down.

  - One of the reasons CSS animations are faster than jQuery animations is because animations in CSS utilize hardware acceleration - using the power of the GPU to increase animation performance.
- Likewise you can also improve jQuery animations by using [Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/) or [GSAP](https://greensock.com/get-started-js). Both of these libraries can be used with or without jQuery. Velocity uses the same API as jQuery animate method and GSAP provides it's own jQuery plugin.
- Use [jQuery 3.0](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#feature-animations-now-use-requestanimationframe) or greater because it utilizes the native JavaScript [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will give it a try by using CSS animations or using GSAP. It is good to hear that the iPhone X is able to run the code without any issue.